# Filter queryset based on values in the other queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following model in django:

```py
class EmailSubscriber(BaseSubscriber):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField()
```

Now let's say I made a queryset from `EmailSubscriber` Like below:

```py
queryset1 = EmailSubscriber.objects.all()
```

Now I create another queryset like below:

```py
queryset2 = EmailSubscriber.objects.filter(some filters)
```

I want to exclude those fields in `queryset1` that have their email and name in `queryset2`. I mean, if a record in `queryset1` has `{"email": "john@gmail.com", "name": "john"}` and there is a record in `queryset2` with `{"email": "john@gmail.com", "name": "john"}`, the record in `queryset1` must be excluded. So they must be unique together. The thing is, I can't just use `some filters` to exclude from `queryset1`. Assume I have a function that receives `queryset1` and `queryset2` and it returns the desired queryset. How can I do that in an efficient way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) for that, like this:

```
EmailSubscriber.objects.filter(some filters).exclude(pk__in=queryset1.values_list("pk", flat=True))
```

Comment: I updated the question. I can't just do that. Let's say I don't have access to `some filters`. So I have this `queryset2` given to me and I must use it to do my excluding.

Comment: I've updated my answer, django querysets are [lazily evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) so you can still call more functions on your queryset.

Answer (score 0):

After some trying, I came up with this code which works, but I'm not sure if its the most optimal solution.

```py
def exclude_unique(queryset1: QuerySet, queryset2: QuerySet,
                   unique_fields: List[str]) -> QuerySet:
    q_objects = Q()
    for field in unique_fields:
        values = queryset2.values_list(field, flat=True)
        q_objects &= Q(**{f"{field}__in": values})

    return queryset1.exclude(q_objects)
```